# Creating custom http header for test -

Tags: c#, http-headers, request, response

I am coding a Authorisation Management Module with c#. The credentials will be extracted from the http header.
My problem is :
I only have the definition of how the http header will look like(txt file). So I need to prepare the header in the code for test, (adding keys and values to the header in default.aspx) :

```
Response.AppendHeader("contractualData", "03346-b0-t-vg");
Response.AppendHeader("Location", "Default.aspx");
Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

and than when I read the header in page2.aspx pageload with

```
Request.Headers["contractualData"];
```

I cannot see the newly added keys and values.(I can see it is there in response header with IEWatch, but I cant read it with request.headers. I have also tried with Response.AddHeader or Response.Headers.Add. Same behaviour!)  What should I do?

In general, how can I prepare a custom header and test my code with that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Creating a request header and posting it. The following code works :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {


            string path = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + "/";

            myRedirect(path + "TestRedirectTo.aspx", "test", "testValue");

        }

        protected void myRedirect(string url, string headerName, string headerValue)

        {

            Response.Clear();

            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Headers.Add(headerName, headerValue);

            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);


            string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

            sr.Close();

            Response.Write(content);

            sr.Close();

            Response.End();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm getting things backward - in the sending page request is used to send the headers. In the receiving page request should be used to read them.

Comment: That does not sound right. Can you explain what you mean? Request.Headers.Add() gives System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.